# Best way to save user view counts for advertisements in PHP & REST API

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have a REST API built with PHP & MySQL for storing ads.
My database contains an `ads` table and a `users` table.

I want to bump the view count for every `ad` once a user is viewing it (only once, if he views it for the 2nd time, I don't want to raise the count again).

Also, how do I go about setting up a service for the client? Psychologically it seems very aggressive to make a server request each time a user is watching an `ad`, it could get to hundreds of requests at the same time.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You could do the check based on his IP address, and you could also set a cookie that he has already viewed the ad. Then whenever the cookie is set, you don't even query to the db, when the cookie is not present, you check if the user has already seen the ad based on the IP, and insert if they had not seen it yet.

Comment: @Jordy thanks, it could be a great solution if it was a web based app, but it's a REST API for native iOS & Android apps. Unfortunately cookies are out of the question :(